# Symfony form type entity data transformerm

Tags: php, symfony

I have form with field type `entity` on this field I have `query_builder` which return query and `'property' => 'name',`. And my question what need to do in data transformer for change select name, need complicated with several filed, example -  name_address_office. Using Symfony 2.8 I need dataTransformer approach

my form

```
class OutBoundInvoiceRowType extends AbstractType
{
/**
 * @var array
 */
private $vatClasses;

/**
 * @var Container
 */
private $container;

/**
 * @var EntityManager
 */
private $em;

/**
 * OutBoundInvoiceRowType constructor.
 * @param Container $container
 * @param $vatClasses
 */
public function __construct(
    Container $container,    
    $vatClasses
) {
    $this->container = $container;
    $this->vatClasses = $vatClasses;
    $this->em = $this->container->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');
}

/**
 * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
 * @param array $options
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('location', 'entity', array(
            'class' => Location::class,
            'property' => 'name',
            'empty_value' => 'Choice Location',
            'query_builder' => self::getLocations(),
            'required' => false
        ))          
        ->add('vat', ChoiceType::class, [
            'choices' => ?,
            'required' => true,
        ])
    $builder->get('vat')
        ->addModelTransformer(new VatTransformer($this->container));
}
```

and my VatTransformer:

```
class VatTransformer implements DataTransformerInterface
{
    /**
     * @var Container
     */
    private $container;

    /**
     * @var EntityManager
     */
    private $em;

    /**
     * LocationTransformer constructor.
     * @param Container $container
     */
    public function __construct(Container $container)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
        $this->em = $this->container->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param  Location|null $issue
     * @return string
     */
    public function transform($issue)
    {
        if (null === $issue) {
            return '';
        }
    }
}
```

in function transform `$issue` have `null`  and when return `''` nothing change in form, still have `'property' => 'name',` on choice, What need to do in data transform name ?

this now I have

[image]

and this what I need

[image]

need name of several parts

**UPDATE**

Ok. I have choice field `vat` and I need build data in choice for vat field like -  from some entity field, example entity Location (id, name)

How this realized with dataTransformer ?

Comment: A data-transformer is probably not the right solution here. What is it that you actually want to achieve? And what symfony version are you using. Also check the [`choice_label`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html#choice-label) and [`choice_value`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html#choice-value) options.

Comment: Symfony 2.8 I need dataTransformer approach

Comment: Currently there is nothing in your question that would suggest that you *need* a data-transformer. Simply using `choice_label` with a callback would produce the same result. So please add why you think you *need* a data-transformer. For now this looks like you simply *want* to use it, because you don't know how to solve your actual problem.

Comment: Ok. I have choice field `vat` and I need build data in choice for vat field like -  from some entity field, example entity Location (id, name)

How this realized with dataTransformer ?

Comment: So you want to populate the values for `vat` depending on what the user selected in `location`? If so, there is a tutorial for exactly that: https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#form-events-submitted-data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement a `__toString()` method into your entity, which will return the desired name. [Read more on the docs.](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.tostring)

Then you remove the property from the `QueryBuilder`, this will cause the automatic usage of the `to_string()` method of the class.

Comment: ok, thnks, but I need approach with dataTransform, because in this transformer I want add some logic